# drupal hook_update_N()

Tags: 7

1. If I install all updates from site_name/update.php, and after change the system.schema_version from 7005 to 7003 using (to reinstall updates 7004 and 7005)

   UPDATE system SET schema_version = 7003 WHERE name = 'test';
2. I then try to run site_name/update.php but it not run because the fields that `hook_update_N()` adds already exists. And I see when access update.php after error that 2 updates exists.
3. After I restore system.schema_version to its initially value (7005)

Are the updates 7004 and 7005 now installed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the updates 7004 and 7005 now installed or not?

Were they both installed prior to your intentionally trying to break it?

If so, then yes.

If not, then no.

Comment: It was installed, and after i change the system.schema_version from 7005 to 7003 to reinstall it, but I forgot that the fields will remain and I can't reinstall until I not drop that fields from DB.

Comment: I can install from few only one update by it number from drush for example?

Comment: Nope, if you're trying to install/update modules like that you've done something wrong on the way. An update is only to take an old version of a module up to its current state. There's no reinstalling of updates as you put it. If you make a mistake in one update, you'll need another update to rectify that mistake (unless the operation you performed first time round happened to be one that can just be run again with no other interference; obviously creating a field doesn't apply)

Comment: For fields though, you can wrap the creation code in `if (!field_info_field('field_foo')) {` and same for the instance. You should only, ideally, be messing with this stuff if you're confident of what you're doing...mistakes in update hooks can end up being difficult to recover from

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do, and why are you trying to do this? To be honest, it makes no sense. First off, schema numbers should start at 7000 (in Drupal 7), and you should never be resetting them, particularly within hook_update_N(), as you're just going to cause the same code to be run every time the update process is run.

Comment: it start with 7000 and end with 7212, I simplify example. Ok I change

Comment: Ok, your initial post was a little confusing. But I understand what you are saying no1.

After step 1:

At this point, the updates in 7004 and 7005 are installed. However, Drupal thinks they are not, since you have set the version to earlier than these two updates.

After step 2: The updates are still installed. However, Drupal will not be able to perform updates because there will be errors due to the fields already existing.

After step 3: The updates in 7004 and 7005 are installed.

Comment: If you want to re-run updates, you shouldn't actually re-run them. What you should do add more updates to reverse what you have previously done. Example:

    hook_update_7006() {
      // Remove the fields you created in 7004 and 7005
    }

    hook_update_7007() {
      // Add your fields again
      // Do whatever it is you forgot.
    }